# I can't set field property in an Access DB with DAO

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm triyng to change properties in a table (Table1) based in another table (Table2), using DAO

I try:

```
Dim rst as DAO.recodset
dim rstCopy as DAO.recodset

   Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(TablaAOrdenar, dbOpenSnapshot, dbSeeChanges)
   Set rstCopy = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(TablaAOrdenar & "Desdoblada", dbOpenDynaset, dbSeeChanges)

        'Size
        rstCopy.Fields("name").Size = rst.Fields("name").Size

'and I receive error 3219 (operacion no válida)
'How i can do it?
```

Comment: You need a Tabledef object, not Recordset.

Comment: I'm going to try it.

Comment: Review http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4599